# Ads warning in Google Play after implementing firebase-analytics and play-services-analytics

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-analytics, ads

I need both firebase-analytics and play-services-analytics for log Firebase events and tracking INSTALL_REFERRER. After adding the dependencies, I get this warning in Google Play: "We found ad SDKs in your app", with three occurrences.

However, my app does not show any kind of ads.

Do you know how can I avoid the ads warning? This is how I implement Firebase and google play libraries in my app level build gradle file:

```
//Firebase
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3') {
    exclude module: "play-services-ads-identifier"
    exclude module: "play-services-ads"
}
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx') {
    exclude module: "play-services-ads-identifier"
    exclude module: "play-services-ads"
}
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx') {
    exclude module: "play-services-ads-identifier"
    exclude module: "play-services-ads"
}
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx') {
    exclude module: "play-services-ads-identifier"
    exclude module: "play-services-ads"
}
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx') {
    exclude module: "play-services-ads-identifier"
    exclude module: "play-services-ads"
}

//Google
implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:18.0.1') {
    exclude module: "play-services-ads-identifier"
    exclude module: "play-services-ads"
}
implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.0.1') {
    exclude module: "play-services-ads-identifier"
    exclude module: "play-services-ads"
}

implementation('com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2') {
    exclude module: "play-services-ads-identifier"
    exclude module: "play-services-ads"
}
```

I also have these lines in my Android Manifest:

```
<meta-data
     android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled"
     android:value="false" />

<meta-data
     android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated"
     android:value="true" />

<receiver
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:exported="false">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get rid of that warning by excluding the following three modules from analytics in the gradle file. You would think Google would be better equipped to accurately query their own libraries...

```
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx') {
    exclude module: "play-services-ads-identifier"
    exclude module: "play-services-measurement"
    exclude module: "play-services-measurement-sdk"
}
```